# SCORM 1.2 real time tracking

Tags: javascript, php, moodle, scorm, scorm1.2

I am using SCORM 1.2 (Moodle) in my LMS. I am not able to track real time activities of user like how many slide have viewed at any point of time. Also i want to track assessment result in the SCORM content.

Is there any API that will help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Hi Epodox....thanku for your suggestion. I have edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps to see the user's current status:
1. Under Administration, choose 'Grades'
2. Click the title of the course that you are testing.
3. For the student, click the attempt number that you want to see. If they have never finished the course, it will be attempt 1.
4. Click 'Track Details'
5. Moodle will show you a variety of SCORM variables. The exact contents of this screen varies enormously depending on what tool you used to create the SCORM package. Some SCORM packages report "cmi.core.lesson_status", "cmi.core.total_time", "cmi.core.lesson_location", and "cmi.suspend_data". Perhaps you could mention your authoring tool or provide a screenshot of this page in moodle if you need more assistance. Hopefully one of the variables contains the data that you need. If it does not, you need to change the settings in your SCORM authoring tool (not in moodle).

Answer (score 0):

SCORM content can use Interactions which support latency which would present at 'cmi.interactions.n.latency'.  The content would have to utilize this however in order to time track how long the student interacted.

In SCORM 1.2 these features were often 'optional' which is why they could not be relied upon.  They were mandatory in SCORM 2004.